# Running a process in the background on a remote ubuntu server, from an ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, server, remote-access, nohup

I'm trying to use the following command to run a process in the background on a remote Ubuntu server:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh root@HOST 'nohup COMMAND-THAT-BLOCKS &'
```

Unfortunately the process closes.

When I just run

```
'nohup COMMAND-THAT-BLOCKS &'
```

in the remote server console, it works.

My guess is that when I close the ssh connection, the process is being terminated (because its user disconnected)

I would like the process to stay alive, even if its user disconnected.

Comment: I think this should have worked! Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect) and maybe try to redirect stdout/err to a log file or something. I have done this in the past using `screen` as one suggest on the thread. What happens if you don't use `sshpass`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `tmux` or `screen`. I prefer `screen` for its simplicity. You can find `screen` Ubuntu documentation from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen).

- ssh into your remote server. Type *screen*. After that you can start
  the process you want.
- Detach from screen session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. This leaves your process running. After that you can log out of the remote server.
- To resume your screen session log on again and type *screen -r*

You can also name your screen session with *screen -S name*

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way and maybe preferred (depending on what you need) is to use `screen`. Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108223) post you can connect to a remote screen and run a command the following way:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh root@HOST 'screen -r -S "<screenName>" "command/or/script/to/execute"'
```

That will later allow you to interactively connect to `HOST` and attach that screen session, which is not possible with nohup (as far as i know)